# HMVC in Codeigniter - assets folder

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, assets, hmvc

I am developing an app in Codeigniter with HMVC. Right now I have this folder structure:

```
-Aplication
-Assets
--Module1
---js
---css
--Module2
-System
```

But i want migrate each asstets module into module folder

```
-Application
--Modules
---Module1
----assets
----controllers
----views
----models
```

I'm trying everything but without success. I can't access to assets folder placed inside module.

Any idea how can I get access to that folder?

Comment: So there will be another folder like assets in your application and what is the logic of making the folder in module

Comment: because i want to have it separate in module. It is better when you install an module from admin panel. Like in wordpress plugins where each plugin has own folder with assets

Comment: I would have assets out side of application folder. As it's recommended to do so. The htaccess in the application folder blocks it.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 the OP didn't mention anything about not having assets outside the application folder as well. His point is to get specific assets related to a module inside the same module folder, it makes sense and I would be interested in knowing the solution myself. Btw, you can have .htaccess files anywhere you want, if you want all the assets' folders to be blocked you can either have one .htaccess per assets folder or use [`<Directory>` directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) pointing to each module in the root .htaccess...

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/modules/modules1/assets/css/style.css">Link</a>
```

Comment: sure but in source folder you will be able to see whole application path. This app has two interface user and admin

Comment: if i understand what you asked ... make a folder called admin inside assets and another folder for user.
add things what you require where.. 
i hope this makes sense

Comment: i want to have an modular app where i can install module like slider. And what i'm trying to do is place module pack into module folder, with all assets views and logic. and call that module in specyfic place on app. But i cannot get access to assets placed inside module folder and i don't want let user to know the application structure folder

Answer (score 1):

I added an array to the Module class to store the assets and two functions to store/retrieve the items. Here is the source (updated Modules.php)

```
        #Reigister your assets
        public static function register_asset( $asset )
        {
           if( in_array($asset,self::$assets) === FALSE )
           {
              self::$assets[] = $asset;
           }
        }

       public static function assets()
       {
             return self::$assets;
       }
```

and now you can register your assets like this inside your module

```
Modules::register_asset('myslider.js');
```

You can retrieve all your assets using

```
Modules:assets();
```

Which will return an array of assets that can be processed depending up on the situation.